# determine character occurrence in r

Tags: r, data-manipulation

i have a list of domain names (e.g. google.com) and would like to create a data frame consisting of column with domain names, and 26 new columns comprising the letters a-z. the the data frame rows should consist of the counts each letter appears in each domain. i can get it to work for a single row, but not the entire data frame. here is what i have so far:

```
df_letters = data_frame(domain = domain_df$domain)
df_letters[, letters] = 0
head(df_letters)

    # A tibble: 6 × 27
         domain     a     b     c     d     e     f     g     h     i     j     k     l
          <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1    google.com     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
2   youtube.com     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
3  facebook.com     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
4     baidu.com     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
5     yahoo.com     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
6 wikipedia.org     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
# ... with 14 more variables: m <dbl>, n <dbl>, o <dbl>, p <dbl>, q <dbl>, r <dbl>, s <dbl>,
#   t <dbl>, u <dbl>, v <dbl>, w <dbl>, x <dbl>, y <dbl>, z <dbl>
> 

df_letters$domain = str_trim(df_letters$domain, side = "both")

df_letters[, 2:27] = str_count(df_letters$domain, letters)
```

The following warning message appears along with the incorrectly filled df_letters data frame:

```
Warning message:
In stri_count_regex(string, pattern, opts_regex = opts(pattern)) :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length

# A tibble: 6 × 27
         domain     a     b     c     d     e     f     g     h     i     j     k     l
          <chr> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
1    google.com     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
2   youtube.com     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1
3  facebook.com     2     2     2     2     2     2     2     2     2     2     2     2
4     baidu.com     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1
5     yahoo.com     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
6 wikipedia.org     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
# ... with 14 more variables: m <int>, n <int>, o <int>, p <int>, q <int>, r <int>, s <int>,
#   t <int>, u <int>, v <int>, w <int>, x <int>, y <int>, z <int>
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: I think `df_letters[, 2:27] = str_count(df_letters$domain, letters)` you are assigning the output of a single vector to multiple columns 2:27.  THe lengthe of `str_count` may not be same as the nrow of df_letters

Comment: i was hoping to vectorize the operation and avoid using a for loop. i know the following code produces the correct output for a single domain: str_count(df_letters$domain[1], letters). im afraid incrementing through each domain will be computationally expensive for domain lists over a few million

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a base R alternative using `table`, `do.call` and a couple of `*binds`:

```
# data as a vector of strings
sites <- c("google.com", "youtube.com")

# get a list of counts of each letter, remove "."
siteList <- lapply(strsplit(sites, split=""),
                   function(i) table(factor(i, levels=c(".", letters)))[-1])
```

Here, `strsplit` returns a list with each element containing individual characters. This list is fed to `lapply`, which calculates counts of each character with `table` after converting the character vector into a factor. This conversion ensures that each letter is present in the `table` output. The `[-1]` removes "." from the output.

```
# construct data.frame
cbind.data.frame(sites, do.call(rbind, siteList))
        sites a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z
1  google.com 0 0 1 0 1 0 2 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 3 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
2 youtube.com 0 1 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 2 0 0 0 0 1 2 0 0 0 1 0
```

Here, `do.call(rbind, siteList)` returns a matrix with the letters as column names and the counts of each table in the rows. This is converted to a data.frame with `cbind.data.frame`, which also adds the website names.

Comment: thank you. i never took the time to learn the difference between an lapply and do.call operation, and therefor, forgot. this was extremely helpful!